# A variable Value is not getting updated while writing it in the conditional statement in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am reading Profile table from  the database against a certain user id and then assigning it to a variable.
If such profile exists in the database, I want to show a button "Edit Profile". And if profile does not exist against that user id, then there will be a button to say "Create Profile" I wrote the following conditional statement:

```
public function read(){
        $records = DB::table('user_profiles')
                    ->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();

        $status= empty($records) ? 'not_exist' : 'exist';
            return dd($records,$status);
}
```

Then in my blade template, I wrote following code:

```
@if($status === 'exist')
        <button type="button" class="btn mb-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-company-profile">
          Edit Profile
        </button>      
      @else
        ($status === 'not_exist')
        <button type="button" class="btn mb-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-company-profile">
          Create Profile
        </button>
      @endif
```

I want right button to appear on profile page. e.g. If Profile does not exist, then the button should say "Create Profile" and if Profile exist, button should be "Edit Profile". To check the issue in controller function, I did dd($records, $status). The result shows same $status if profile exists or not. So the problem is that my $status variable is not getting updated as required.

Comment: Realistically, the way to go here would be to create a new model for 'user_profiles' and assign a relationship between that and your user. This way we could access it through \Auth::user()->profile, which would either return the model or null.

Answer (score 0):

use the count() method instead on the collection to check if there are any records

```
public function read()
{
    $records = DB::table('user_profiles')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->get();

    $status = $records->count() > 0 ? 'exist' : 'not_exist';
    
    return dd($records, $status);
}
```

---

```
@if($status === 'exist')
    <button type="button" class="btn mb-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-company-profile">
        Edit Profile
    </button>      
@else
    <button type="button" class="btn mb-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-company-profile">
        Create Profile
    </button>
@endif
```